# reset selectizeInputs each time I modify a numericInput in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm learning shiny and working with a numericInput connected to many selectizeInputs.

- if the numeric input equals to 1 or 2, I would like to create respectively 1 and 2  selectizeInputs and select the "i"th modality of a vector called "modalities" for each selectizeInput **EDIT : and that choices = modalities[i] only (and not modalities)**
- if the numeric input equals to 3 or 4, I would like to create respectively 3 and 4  selectizeInputs which are connected with each other (with choices = modalities). In other words : if an item is selected in one of the selectizeinputs i would like that it disappears from the other selectizeinputs' choices.

In addition (and this is what I have trouble with) **I would like to "reset" all the selected SelectizeInputs each time I modify the numericInput.** I tried with the observeEvent below and I tried to use an isolate(input$ui_number) but I did not find any solution to my question because i don't understand how to do it... !

Thank you for your help !

```
      library(shiny)

      modalities <- LETTERS[1:10]

      ui = tabPanel("Change modalities",
                    numericInput("ui_number", label = "Number of modalities",
                                 min = 1, max = 4, value = 3),
                    uiOutput("renderui")
      )

      server = function(input, output, session) {

        # Generate modalities select lists
        output$renderui <- renderUI({
          output = tagList()
          for (i in seq_len(input$ui_number)) {
            output[[i]] = selectizeInput(paste0("ui_mod_choose", i), 
                                         label = paste0("Modality ", i),
                                         choices = modalities, multiple = TRUE)
          }
          return(output)
        })


        # if input$ui_number is modified to 3 or 4 : set selected to NULL ##### NOT WORKING
        observeEvent({input$ui_number},
                     {
                       n <- input$ui_number
                       if(n%in%c(3,4)){
                         for (i in seq_len(n)) {
                           updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("ui_mod_choose",i),selected=NULL)
                         }
                       }

                     }

        )


        observe({

          n <- input$ui_number

          if(n%in%c(1,2)){ #if n=1 or 2 =>  Select the "i"th modality for each selectizeInput
            for (i in seq_len(n)) {
              updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("ui_mod_choose",i),
                                   choices = modalities[i],
                                   selected = modalities[i]
              )
            }

          } else{   # if n=3 or 4 => Remove selected modalities from other select lists
            for (i in seq_len(n)) {
              vecteur <- unlist(lapply((1:n)[-i], function(i) 
                input[[paste0("ui_mod_choose",i)]]))
              updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("ui_mod_choose",i),
                                   choices = setdiff(modalities, vecteur),
                                   selected = input[[paste0("ui_mod_choose",i)]])
            }

          }




        })

      }

      runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

This issue corresponds to the following of this one :

[lapply function using a numericInput parameter around an observeEvent in RShiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655487/lapply-function-using-a-numericinput-parameter-around-an-observeevent-in-rshiny/47664752#47664752)

**EDIT2 : new try thanks to @Aurèle 's tip.**
The only problem which remains is the 1:100 in lapply which can take time to load (did not find a solution to add a reactive content such as 1:input&ui_number around a conditional panel)

```
      library(shiny)

      modalities <- LETTERS[1:10]

      make_conditional_selectizeInputs <- function() {
        do.call(
          div,
          lapply(1:100, function(i)
            conditionalPanel(
              condition = sprintf("%d <= input.ui_number", i),
              selectizeInput(sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i), 
                             label = sprintf("Modality %d", i),
                             choices = character(0), multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL)
            )
          )
        )
      }



      ui <- tabPanel(
        "Change modalities",
        uiOutput("rendernumeric"),
        #numericInput("ui_number", label = "Number of modalities", min = 1L, max = max, value = 1L),
        make_conditional_selectizeInputs()
      )


      server <- function(input, output, session) {

        max <- 4

        output$rendernumeric <- renderUI({
          numericInput("ui_number", label = "Number of modalities", min = 1L, max = max, value = 1L)
        })





        n <- reactive({
          n <- input$ui_number
          if (is.null(n) || is.na(n) || !n >= 0) 0 else n
        })

        # Reset all
        observeEvent(
          eventExpr = n(), 
          handlerExpr = for (i in seq_len(max))
            updateSelectizeInput(
              session, sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i),
              choices = if (n() %in% 1:2 && i <= n()) modalities[i] else modalities, 
              selected = if (n() %in% 1:2 && i <= n()) modalities[i] else NULL
            )
        )

        all_selected <- reactive({
          unlist(lapply(seq_len(max), function(i) 
            input[[sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i)]]))
        })

        # Update available modalities
        observeEvent(
          eventExpr = all_selected(),
          handlerExpr = if (!n() %in% 1:2) for (i in seq_len(n())) {
            x <- input[[sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i)]]
            other_selected <- setdiff(all_selected(), x)
            updateSelectizeInput(session, sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i),
                                 choices = setdiff(modalities, other_selected),
                                 selected = x)
          }
        )

      }

      runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just need one more line: `selected = if (n %in% 1:2) modalities[i] else NULL` whenever you regenerate your `selectizeInput`s.

```
library(shiny)

modalities <- LETTERS[1:10]

ui = tabPanel("Change modalities",
              numericInput("ui_number", label = "Number of modalities",
                           min = 1, max = 4, value = 3),
              uiOutput("renderui"))

server = function(input, output, session) {

  # Generate modalities select lists
  output$renderui <- renderUI({
    output = tagList()
    n <- input$ui_number
    n <- if (is.null(n) || is.na(n) || ! n >= 0) 0 else n
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
      output[[i]] = selectizeInput(paste0("ui_mod_choose", i), 
                                   label = paste0("Modality ", i),
                                   choices = if (n %in% 1:2) modalities[i] else modalities, 
                                   multiple = TRUE,
                                   # Add this
                                   selected = if (n %in% 1:2) modalities[i] else NULL)
    }
    output
  })

  # Remove selected modalities from other select lists
  observe({
    n <- isolate(input$ui_number)
    if (!n %in% 1:2) for (i in seq_len(n)) {
      vecteur <- unlist(lapply((1:n)[-i], function(i) 
        input[[paste0("ui_mod_choose",i)]]))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, paste0("ui_mod_choose",i),
                           choices = setdiff(modalities, vecteur),
                           selected = input[[paste0("ui_mod_choose",i)]])
    }
  })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Comment: Thank you for your tips but it is still not exactly what I want (my fault : I did not mention it properly at the beginning) :
When n %in c(1,2) I would like that selected = modalities[i] (what you did) but I also would like that choices = modalities[i] and not modalities... And what i tried still does not work... (see edit). I really have some difficulties in knowing what to put in renderUI, in updateSelectizeInput, when isolate n... Even if i'm starting to understand things thanks to your examples.

Comment: See my edit: `if (!n %in% 1:2) for (....` instead of `for (....`. `isolate()` is used here to avoid an unnecessary dependency on `input$ui_number`. Strive for simplicity (easier said than done): only add dependencies when really needed. Don't worry too much about not understanding `updateSelectizeInput`, it's more of an edge case/a hack in Shiny. For a better understanding of Shiny's *reactivity*, the resources at shiny.rstudio.com are invaluable. Also: set `options(shiny.reactlog=TRUE)`, then run your app, play a bit with it, then hit `Ctrl`+`F3` for a graphical model of what's happening

Comment: Thank you for your tricks, i'll try to learn how to use shiny.reactlog. I started to play with the app. I replaced numericInput(value = 3) to numericInput(value = 1) and the app stopped working :(  => when i choose input$ui_number=3 the selectizeinputs are not connected with each other anymore and I cannot understand why is that !!

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce. It's because the `if (!n %in% 1:2)` somehow makes us lose the dependency on the `input$ui_mod_choosei`s.

Comment: This is partly why everytime i've been trying something during the past 3 days, it failed. I really do not understand this lost of dependency. Do you think it is possible to find a solution which works in every case ?

Comment: Yes. See my other answer

Answer (score 1):

(This is different enough to be a separate answer).

In https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html, four different approaches to a dynamic UI in Shiny are suggested, ordered by difficulty:

> - The `conditionalPanel` function, which is used in `ui.R` and wraps a set of UI elements that need to be dynamically shown/hidden.
> - The `renderUI` function, which is used in `server.R` in conjunction with the `uiOutput` function in `ui.R`, lets you generate calls to UI functions and make the results appear in a predetermined place in the UI.
> - The `insertUI` and `removeUI` functions, which are used in server.R and allow you to add and remove arbitrary chunks of UI code (all independent from one another), as many times as you want, whenever you want, wherever you want.
> - Use JavaScript to modify the webpage

Your attempts use the second approach, this answer uses the first one (though it should be doable with any of them):

```
library(shiny)

modalities <- LETTERS[1:10]
max <- 4L
```

First, a helper function to build the UI. The number of `selectizeInput`s is no longer dynamic but fixed to `max`, and they're alternatively shown/hidden based on `input$ui_number`:

```
make_conditional_selectizeInputs <- function(max) {
  do.call(
    div,
    lapply(seq_len(max), function(i)
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = sprintf("%d <= input.ui_number", i),
        selectizeInput(sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i), 
                       label = sprintf("Modality %d", i),
                       choices = character(0), multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL)
      )
    )
  )
}

ui <- tabPanel(
  "Change modalities",
  numericInput("ui_number", label = "Number of modalities",
               min = 1L, max = max, value = 1L),
  make_conditional_selectizeInputs(max)
)
```

The server function has two reactive expressions that help modularize code but are not essential to its logic (`n()` and `all_expected()`).

There is no longer a `renderUI()` (the `selectizeInput`s are already generated once and for all).

There is an `observeEvent()` that takes a dependency on `input$ui_number` and resets all selections and choices when it changes.

The last `observeEvent()` takes a dependency on all `input$ui_mod_choose[i]` and updates all the choices whenever there is a new selection.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  n <- reactive({
    n <- input$ui_number
    if (is.null(n) || is.na(n) || !n >= 0) 0 else n
  })

  # Reset all
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = n(), 
    handlerExpr = for (i in seq_len(max))
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session, sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i),
        choices = if (n() %in% 1:2 && i <= n()) modalities[i] else modalities, 
        selected = if (n() %in% 1:2 && i <= n()) modalities[i] else NULL
      )
  )

  all_selected <- reactive({
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(max), function(i) 
      input[[sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i)]]))
  })

  # Update available modalities
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = all_selected(),
    handlerExpr = if (!n() %in% 1:2) for (i in seq_len(n())) {
      x <- input[[sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i)]]
      other_selected <- setdiff(all_selected(), x)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, sprintf("ui_mod_choose%d", i),
                           choices = setdiff(modalities, other_selected),
                           selected = x)
    }
  )

}
```

Essentially it differs from the second approach (with `renderUI`) in that it removes part of the dependency between `input$ui_number` and the `input$ui_mod_choose[i]`, at least when they're generated (but there's a residual dependency when they're reset because of `updateSelectizeInput`. I'm not completely clear why I could make it work with this approach and not with `renderUI` though).

```
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

This is a screenshot of the reactlog, though it doesn't show the whole picture, because of the necessary *impurity* of `updateSelectizeInput()` that mixes the UI and server logics, and creates circular dependencies that can be tricky to reason about:

[image: screenshot of reactlog]

Comment: I already said that but first : a real thank you for your help and for helping me understanding what i would define as a quite high level in shiny :) I really enjoyed learning this new method. And this method is working perfectly ! However (sorry again an however but i like to understand every step of the reflexion) in my real app my max in not a fixed value but is also depending on the value of another selectInput (reactive value). And as I have to declare it as a global variable in your example i'm not sure i could reproduce this method for my real app.

Comment: I found a way (see EDIT 2) to do it with a lapply(1:100.. It is not really optimal to do it if "max" can be a high value but I did not find another way !